# How to write better TypeScript type to solve two errors

Tags: typescript

Sorry guys if the title is not clear not sure in this particular case how i should name it.

So i have my object

```
export const screenSizes: typeScreenSizes = {
  // xxs: '320px', // iPhone 5/SE
  // xs: '375px', // iPhone X
  sm: '576px', // Mobile
  md: '768px', // iPad
  lg: '992px', // Laptop
  xl: '1200px', // Desktop
}
```

And i'm using this in two different places different way.

1st place

```
export const mq = (n: string) => `@media (min-width: ${screenSizes[n]})`
```

2nd place

```
createBreakpoints(screenSizes)
```

In both of those instances I'm getting TS error, so to fix'ish them i wrote my type like so

```
export type typeScreenSizes = {
  [T: string]: string
  sm: string
  md: string
  lg: string
  xl: string
}
```

But I'm sure this is not right, but I'm not sure how can i write this better, i think Generic i need to use?

1st Error:
[image]

2nd Error:
[image]

Comment: Do you use strict ,not alwaysStrict (Strict > always Strict,It doesn't allow many things,Stricter type judgment

Comment: yep strict = true

Comment: This is a bad habit, but you can switch to alwaysStrict

Comment: hm why is it bad habit to use strict only?

Comment: Compared with strict mode, always strict use incompletetype//in tsconfig => alwaysStrict != strict

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`screenSizes` is an object of type `typeScreenSizes` with members `sm`, `md`, `lg` and `xl`. To index this object you are allowed to use either one of these four values. But string is too generic to index it, because it could also be `abc` for example which is not a member of the type `typeScreenSizes`.

To fix this problem you have to change the type of the parameter in `mq` to only allow one of the four values above:

```
export const mq = (n: keyof typeScreenSizes) => `@media (min-width: ${screenSizes[n]})`
```

Answer (score 2):

"key" != string
you should use
`const mq = (n:"sm"|"md"|"lg"|"xl")=>screenSizesO[n]`
or
`const mq = (n:keyof typeScreenSizesO)=>screenSizesO[n]`